# How to refresh my animation sequence when all of my animations are done

Tags: css, animation

I have multiple divs with animations, created in CSS, on my page. When the last div with animation is finished animating I wish to have the whole sequence to start over. My animations all have different delay times, and animations. I've tried the "animation: infinite" but what that achieves is the each individual animation will run again immediately after the animation has finshed. I need it start from the beginning after all of the animations have completed.

Anyone know how to achieve this?

Sample CSS

```
.openDiv {
    width: 0px;
    height: 513px;
    background-image: url("CLS-circle-Ring-faded.png");
    animation-name: grow;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    transition-delay: 10s;
    -webkit-animation-name: grow;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 10s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes grow {
    0% {
        width: 0px;
    }

    100% {
        width: 1379px;
    }
} /* Standard syntax */@keyframes grow {
    0% {
        width: 0px;
    }

    100% {
        width: 1379px;
    }
}
```

Comment: For restarting animations you need to remove and add class again. [See here](http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)

Comment: What are you using to control the animation sequence, JavaScript? Show us the relevant code, if possible.

Comment: ^anpsmn thank you for that link. I will check it out. I think that might help.

Comment: Telmo no javascript function. example of code: .openDiv { width: 0px; height: 513px; background-image: url("CLS-circle-Ring-faded.png"); animation-name: grow; animation-duration: 2s; animation-fill-mode: forwards; animation-delay: 2s; transition-delay: 10s;-webkit-animation-name: grow; -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; -webkit-transition-delay:10s; }
@-webkit-keyframes grow {     0% { width: 0px; }  100% { width: 1379px; } } /* Standard syntax */ @keyframes grow {   0% { width: 0px; }  100% { width: 1379px; }}

Comment: If you're not using JS, try to remove and add the CSS class as previously stated.